# Splitting pandas column from 2D array into separate columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe that currently has multiple lists of 2D arrays that looks something like

```
0 [[AA, 2], [AB, 1], [AC, 1]]
1 [[AA, 3], [AC, 2], [AE, 1]]
2 [[AB, 2], [AC, 1], [AD, 1]]
```

Is there any way to separately create a data frame from this that looks like this

```
   AA AB AC AD AE
0  2  1  1  0  0
1  3  0  2  0  1
2  0  2  1  1  0
```

If `x = [[AA, 2], [AB, 1], [AC, 1], [AA, 3], [AC, 2], [AE, 1],[AB, 2], [AC, 1], [AD, 1]]`

then right now I have

```
arr = []
for i in x:
  i = np.array(i)
  arr.append(i)

df = pd.DataFrame(arr)
```

And I can single out the first AA by doing `x[0][0][0]` but I don't think that is the right step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use list comprehension with convert values to dictionaries and pass to `DataFrame` constructor:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col':[[['AA', 2], ['AB', 1], ['AC', 1]],
                          [['AA', 3], ['AC', 2], ['AE', 1]],
                          [['AB', 2], ['AC', 1], ['AD', 1]]]})
print (df)
                           col
0  [[AA, 2], [AB, 1], [AC, 1]]
1  [[AA, 3], [AC, 2], [AE, 1]]
2  [[AB, 2], [AC, 1], [AD, 1]]

df1 = pd.DataFrame([dict(x) for x in df['col']]).fillna(0)
    
print (df1)
    AA   AB  AC   AE   AD
0  2.0  1.0   1  0.0  0.0
1  3.0  0.0   2  1.0  0.0
2  0.0  2.0   1  0.0  1.0
```